# How to get the currentSlot and change the helm upgrade command with the new slot on Azure devops?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-aks

I am trying to implement CI/CD pipeline for my APIs on AKS. i have successfully configured the CI and CD pipelines which works quite smoothly, now i have 2 environments named Prod and Slot to enable 0 down time.

I found the [`blue/green deployment`](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BlueGreenDeployment.html) method. And in my CD pipeline i am trying to set the current slot and pass it to the helm upgrade command in the next step

```
currentSlot=`(helm --client-only get values --all api-poi | grep -Po 'productionSlot: \K.*')`

if [ "$currentSlot" == "blue" ]; then
    newSlot="green"
else
    newSlot="blue"
fi
```

but it always set the newslot as empty. what could be the reason?

```
$(newSlot).enabled=true
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with Azure CLI command instead of Bash script with the **`az aks get-credentials --name`**  involved.

Alternate CLI command would be

```
az aks get-credentials --name $(AKSClusterName) --resource-group $(AKSResourceGroup)
currentSlot=$(helm get values --all $(chartName) |  grep -oP '(?<=productionSlot: ).*')
if [ "$currentSlot" == "blue" ]; then
    newSlot="green"
else
    newSlot="blue"
fi
```

you need to set those AKSClusterName,AKSResourceGroup,chartName values in the pipeline or hard code them